# subprocess fails in line 1420, Win error 2 [system cannot find the file specified]

Tags: python-3.x, github, spyder

I'm not a coder but need to view a specific code from github (https://github.com/SimpleLab-Inc/wsb)
I'm on Python IDE spyder and while running the subprocess package i keep getting my code stuck in line 1420.

```
import os
import datetime
import subprocess
import inspect
import sys

subprocess('dir', shell=True)


print(inspect.getfile(lambda: None))
os.environ['C:/Program Files/Python311/Scripts'] = "1"
__file__= 'run_pipeline.py'
def run_task(task_name: str, script: str):

    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    print("\n\n--------------------------------------")
    print(task_name)
    print("--------------------------------------\n")

    if script.lower().endswith(".r"):

        output = subprocess.check_output(
            ["rscript", os.path.join("src", script)],
            # We're in /src, R expects us to be in project root
            cwd=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."))

        print(output.decode("UTF-8"))

    elif script.lower().endswith(".py"):

        # Replace / with . because we're importing them as modules
        __import__(script.lower().replace('.py', '').replace("/", "."))

    else:
        raise Exception("Unrecognized script format.")

    print(f"Elapsed time: {(datetime.datetime.now() - start_time).total_seconds() / 60:.2f} minutes")
    
path = 'C:/Users/PaulaCabotJaume/Desktop/USWaterMode/wsb-develop/src/downloaders'
os.listdir(path)
files = os.listdir(path)
files = [f for f in files if f.lower().endswith("_wsb.R")]
for f in files:
    run_task(
        f"Downloading {f[9:11].upper()}",
        "downloaders/states/" + f)

#%%
# Download ECHO (30 secs)
run_task(
    "Downloading ECHO admin data",
    "downloaders/download_echo.R")

#%%
# Download FRS (1.5 mins)
run_task(
    "Downloading FRS centroids", 
    "downloaders/download_frs.R")

#%%
# Download MHP (10 secs)
run_task(
    "Downloading mobile home parks point data", 
    "downloaders/download_mhp.R")

#%%
# Download SDWIS (5 mins)
run_task(
    "Downloading SDWIS data", 
    "downloaders/download_sdwis.py")

#%%
# Download TIGER (3 mins)
run_task(
    "Downloading TIGRIS places and Natural Earth coastline", 
    "downloaders/download_tigris_ne.R")

#%%
# Download UCMR (10 secs)
run_task(
    "Downloading UCMR occurrence data", 
    "downloaders/download_ucmr.R")

#%%
# Download Contributed PWS (10 secs)
run_task(
    "Downloading contributed pws boundaries",
    "downloaders/download_contributed_pws.R")
```

The idea that by running them I can download them and then transform them into csv. Any help is appreciated.